# Tool to upload modified files over FTP

Tags: command-line, upload, ftp

I know there's similar questions on here, but they all seem to end up with a recommended answer that wouldn't suit mine - possibly more specific requirements; I'm dealing with a rubbish shared host.

I'm wondering if there is a command-line tool which can do a one-way sync over FTP, i.e. it will upload new or modified files, given a host, username, password, etc..

I know rsync can do this, but unfortunately in this instance I can't use it.

If there is no such tool, does FTP support any kind of hashing (md5, sha1, etc) so I could make my own.

The ultimate goal here is to have this running automatically, as a git hook, or makefile script.

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing magical about rsync. In its default mode, it just looks at the size and modification time of the file, which you've already got available to you with *any* ftp client. You can easily write a script to copy files with a newer mtime or different size than the server's.

Comment: are you on windows? I heard good things about WinSCP synchronization features

Comment: @Adithya I've used WinSCP on Windows, and it does have a feature that would be perfect if it were command-line. As far as I know, it can't be run like that.

Comment: @Chris Would the mtime be reliable, given that the client and server might have different times set?

Comment: typically the mtime is just a number independent of the hosts clock. So you send a file, set the mtime manually to the mtime of the local file, and you're done. The fact that that number represents a time is unimportant. Think of it more as a revision number of sorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since asking this question, I've found [git-ftp](https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp) which works really well, assuming you can keep all your files under git.

I'm using something along the lines of `git add .;git commit -m "Recent changes";git ftp push` to upload modified files.